# Where is the Netsuite Webservices Postman Collection?

Tags: rest, web-services, postman, netsuite, postman-collection

In Netsuite's REST web services help documentation, there's a reference to a Postman collection:
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/86958/kw/postman

> You can download the REST web services Postman environment template and collection of sample requests from the SuiteTalk tools download page at https://[accountID].app.netsuite.com/app/external/integration/integrationDownloadPage.nl. To access the page, you must substitute your account ID in the URL.
>
> Note To access the Postman environment template and collection, the REST Web Services feature must be enabled, and you must have the REST web services permission assigned to your role. For more information, see REST Web Services Prerequisites and Setup.

However, when I go to the download page (with the correct account ID and REST web services permission), there's only a download available for "NetSuiteDataLoader.zip", which does not contain the postman collection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured this out, a few pages deep in the documentation.

REST web services need to be enabled on the account first.
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/87117

1. Setup > Company > Enable Features (Setup Tasks)
2. Click "Suite Cloud" tab
3. Scroll to "SuiteTalk (Web Services)" section.
4. Tick "REST WEB SERVICES (BETA)" and accept the T&Cs.

You also need to be a user with REST Web Services and SuiteAnalytics Workbook permissions. 
Administrator already has these, but if you need to add them:

1. Go to Setup > Users/Roles > User Management > Manage Users.
2. Locate the role you want to modify. Click the corresponding Edit or Customize link.
3. On the Permissions subtab, click Setup.
4. In the Permission list, select REST Web Services.
5. In the Level list, select Full.
6. Click Add.
7. On the Permissions subtab, click Reports.
8. In the Permission list, select SuiteAnalytics Workbook.
9. In the Level list, select Full.
10. Click Add.
11. Click Save.

Once all that is done, when you go to https://[accountID].app.netsuite.com/app/external/integration/integrationDownloadPage.nl
you will see a link to **NetSuiteRestApiSampleRequests.zip** - which contains the postman collection.

Comment: Hello, I am using the zip which contains postman collection and given all the required parameters but i am getting an error "You must use account-specific domains with the REST Web Services endpoints. Go to Setup > Company > Company Information in the NetSuite UI." Can you help me regarding the issue, please?

Comment: I've messaged you in chat.

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work try to put a tick on WEB SERVICES ONLY ROLE
Setup > Users\Roles > Manage Users >
Find the current role that you want to give access to and Save.

After entering ID of your account on that current role - you will see another folder with NetSuite REST API Sample Requests name.